# Array index to what's the Sub-matrix?

Tags: arrays, matrix, indexing, position

[Tic Tac Toe - Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLew6.jpg)

This is Ultimate Tic Tac Toe game
This is actually an array with size 81.
My question is .. **having the array index of a position how can I know which sub board belongs to it.**

For better clarification see the examples below V

```
(0,0) => a[0], and the position is on the first sub-board 
(0,3) => a[3], and the position is on the second sub-board
```

Basically I want to convert its **position in the array** to the corresponding **sub board**.

Is there any formula for this ?

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question, so I will give some hint, but beyond this you can improve the idea further (try utilizing % operator). Just by looking at the image you provided, you could compare the indices of the current position (i,j) against values corresponding to each sub-boards possible range of valid (i,j).

For example, sub-board 3, corresponds to any position with indices (i,j) where 0 <= i <= 2 and 6 <= j <= 8.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was thinknig this for a day already. I guess i was going for a much difficult aproach.

Comment: I know the feeling :). I bet if you try this out you will find a better approach along the way.